# Read config value from laravel helper

Tags: php, laravel, helper, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to get a config value from my custom helper in laravel 5.6:

```
function current(string $conn=null){
    return $conn.config('server.current');
}
```

but I get this error:

```
Can't use function return value in write context in...
```

There is any other way to share it between helpers?

Laravel seems to not show config values in helpers.

Comment: `.` is the concatenation operator in PHP. If you're attempting to access an array key, then it would be `$conn['config']`. I'd suggest making sure that $conn is not null/an array before you attempt that, though, since that's the default value.

Comment: @aynber no, I'm concatenating the values... that's what I want.

Comment: show us where you called this function.. it sounds like there is an problem.. not in the function declaration

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Try calling the config function and see what it returns. `Log::info(config('server.current')); Log::info($conn);`. They may not be returning what you think they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`current()` is an existing function http://php.net/manual/en/function.current.php